# Outlet inside the wallboard

Tags: electrical

I read all the information and answers given in response to this same question and I readily acknowledge why this isn't a good idea but hear me out with my issue.

I have a tablet. It has been provided to me by ADT for security purposes to arm and disarm the home. The tablet comes with 6' of attached wiring and an adapter which you plug into a nearby outlet.

The tablet is anchored to the wall near the back door just above a light switch. Cannot use the light switch for power as it is a slave switch to another light switch on the opposite side of the room.  So I have the tablet secured and the wires droop down maybe 4' to the outlet where the adapter is plugged in.  There is extra wire on the floor.

I can take care of the wire issue but the whole setup looks stupid and unattractive.

If I can't hide the whole setup in the wall what are my options?

Comment: Just a comment because too short for an answer and I don't have time for a full answer (I'll delete this once someone writes a real answer): [wiremold](https://amzn.to/2GGj19A).

Comment: I would guess we'll need some pictures of the stupid and unattractive installation before attempting to give a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the wall as long as you have an accessible cover that doesn’t damage the finish. For years I have done this and made “picture frames” that were held in with Velcro, an inspector mentioned that I could screw them in it would still be legal he thought my picture frame idea was a good one. So yes you can conceal things they just need to be accessible without damaging the building finish.

Comment: I used a vent register and Velcro to cover up a box in a ceiling.  Inspector said it was too well hidden so he wanted a note in the panel next to the breaker explaining  the location. +1

Comment: That sounds like a good idea I might have to borrow that one.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the electrical outlet out and look behind it at the back of the jbox it is in.  If you are lucky it will be plastic or there will be a strain relief inside the jbox.  If you can remove that then it will allow you access to a hole in the jbox for another piece of romex.

Then cut a large access hole behind where the tablet is mounted, run a fishtape up from the jbox to the large hole, pull your romex back down and junction it in with the electrical outlet.

Then install an in-wall large recessed box - if you lack wall depth look up "low profile recessed wall box for shallow walls" This will have enough space for the wall wart, and it's cables.  The tablet can be mounted on top of that.